# Setting runs in solc options at brownie-config.yaml

Tags: brownie, solc

My goal is to set the `runs` key of solc to the value of `100` inside the brownie-config.yaml file. I have found two different solutions and I would like to know what is the difference between the two in practice. `solution 2` is a sample from the [official Brownie docs](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html), `solution 1` was found elsewhere. Do they set the same `runs` value or `solc[runs]`, `solc[optimizer][runs]` has a different purpose?

```
// solution 1
compiler:
  solc:
    optimize: true
    runs: 100
    remappings:

// solution 2
compiler:
    solc:
        optimizer:
            enabled: true
            runs: 200
        remappings: null
```